# burp: The proxy server is refusing connections from another computer

Tags: 12.04, networking, proxy

Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS (Precise) 32-bit desktop.

I have installed [burp](http://portswigger.net/burp/) (an intercepting Proxy), and it works for
programs run from the same computer, but when I try to connect from
another computer on the same network, I get "The proxy server is refusing connections" error.

I also tried squid3, but could not get it working: it refuses connections even from the same computer.

**How do I set up a proxy on an Ubuntu Precise Desktop system to use it from different computers?**

Comment: OMG, a question from 2014 got downvoted in 2023, when neither that version of Burp nor that version of Ubuntu is used anymore by anybody!

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

Install squid:

```
sudo -i
apt-get update
apt-get install squid3
```

Configure Squid

```
sudo -i
nano /etc/squid3/squid.conf
```

Paste these five lines on file:

```
auth_param digest program /usr/lib/squid3/digest_pw_auth -c /etc/squid3/passwords
auth_param digest realm proxy
acl authenticated proxy_auth REQUIRED
http_access allow authenticated
http_port 3128
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>, save file. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, close nano.

Setting up a users:

```
sudo -i
htdigest -c /etc/squid3/passwords proxy user01
htdigest  /etc/squid3/passwords proxy user02
htdigest  /etc/squid3/passwords proxy user03
```

Run Squid:

```
sudo -i
service squid3 restart
```

Check who is using a proxy:

```
sudo -i
tail -f /var/log/squid3/access.log
```