# HTTP Proxy Using Squid on Ubuntu 12.04 and anonymizing the traffic

Tags: proxy, squid

I read [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/539295/burp-the-proxy-server-is-refusing-connections-from-another-computer/618017#618017) great step-by-step. I would like to use this and anonymize the traffic too.

Basically I want to create an HTTP Proxy Using Squid on Ubuntu 12.04 and anonymizing the traffic. The proxy will be reached from non-local sources. I used [this](https://www.linode.com/docs/networking/squid/squid-http-proxy-ubuntu-12-04) tutorial initially but although it works with some programs it apparently does not allow for browsers to get http-data for some reason ("the proxy servers is refusing connections" is what my browser tells me).

So: I would like to use the step-by-step (first link) and add the lines to anonymize the traffic. How would one go about that?

My idea is to just add the code below to the squid.conf file:

```
  forwarded_for off
  request_header_access Allow allow all
  request_header_access Authorization allow all
  request_header_access WWW-Authenticate allow all
  request_header_access Proxy-Authorization allow all
  request_header_access Proxy-Authenticate allow all
  request_header_access Cache-Control allow all
  request_header_access Content-Encoding allow all
  request_header_access Content-Length allow all
  request_header_access Content-Type allow all
  request_header_access Date allow all
  request_header_access Expires allow all
  request_header_access Host allow all
  request_header_access If-Modified-Since allow all
  request_header_access Last-Modified allow all
  request_header_access Location allow all
  request_header_access Pragma allow all
  request_header_access Accept allow all
  request_header_access Accept-Charset allow all
  request_header_access Accept-Encoding allow all
  request_header_access Accept-Language allow all
  request_header_access Content-Language allow all
  request_header_access Mime-Version allow all
  request_header_access Retry-After allow all
  request_header_access Title allow all
  request_header_access Connection allow all
  request_header_access Proxy-Connection allow all
  request_header_access User-Agent allow all
  request_header_access Cookie allow all
  request_header_access All deny all
```

But then I am absolutely not sure if that holds up, and I would like to know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Looks good to me. It matches my proxy settings except that the first line for you comes after all of my "request_header_access ..." lines.

That line `forwarded_for off` is what makes the difference between your true client IP being passed as the originating IP (on) or the proxy's IP being used as the origin (off). This is important when trying to access geo-specific resources from outside of the allowed geographic location.

For insurance I also have `always_direct deny all` as the last line in the file to make sure that no traffic is passed directly to the client. All traffic must go through the proxy.